# if the if block tests true then i want it to skip the else block but it doesnt :( how can i fix it ? also i am just learning how to programme

Tags: xcode

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int num1, num2, num3;

    printf("Please enter three numbers from the following combinations.\n 1 4 3, 3 3 9,3 3 4, 7 6 3");

    scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
    {
    if ((num1 == 1) && (num2 == 4) && (num3 ==3))
        printf("I love you too :)\n");

    if ((num1 == 3) && (num2 == 3) && (num3 ==9))
        printf("YOU ARE BEAUTIFUL !\n");

    if ((num1 == 3) && (num2 == 3) && (num3 == 4))
        printf("You are best!\n");

    if ((num1 == 7) && (num2 == 6) && (num3 == 3))
        printf("Anubhav misses you !\n");
```

// now i want it to go to else if the above is false but it also does that even if its true
    else
        printf("You entered %d %d %d\n", num1 ,num2, num3);
        printf("This has not been included by this amateur programmer :(\n");

```
    }

printf("I still remember about the calculator :D\n");

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question right... Each of your 'if' statements (after the first) needs to be an else-if. And since you have multiple lines in the ending 'else' clause, you'll need to wrap those two in braces. Like this:

```
if ....
else if ((num1 == 3) && (num2 == 3) && (num3 == 4))
    printf("You are best!\n");
else if ((num1 == 7) && (num2 == 6) && (num3 == 3))
    printf("Anubhav misses you !\n");
else {
    printf("You entered %d %d %d\n", num1 ,num2, num3); 
    printf("This has not been included by this amateur programmer :(\n");
}
```

Comment: yes that works ! can you tell me how that makes a difference ??? please AND THANK YOU !!

Comment: Before, every 'if' was going to get tested and then finally the else was only attached to the last 'if'. So the else block would run whenever that last 'if' failed. Now, all the if statements have to fail in order for the else block to be executed. If any of the if statements are entered, it won't get to the rest of the 'else' statements. Oh, and I think your program is very sweet :)